# How does networkx's from_numpy_matrix() generates edge list?

Tags: python, networkx

I was loading a adjacency matrix file using:

```
adj_matrix = np.load('adj.npy')
```

[image: adj matrix]

A glance of the matrix is shown here. It's easy to see that there is an edge from `Vertex 13` to `Vertex 0`, while there is no edge from `Vertex 0` to `Vertex 13`.

However, when I tried to generate a graph from this adjacency matrix, using

```
G = networkx.from_numpy_matrix(adj_matrix)
G.edges
```

[image: G edges]

networkx generates an edge for `(Vertex 0, Vertex 13)`, not `(Vertex 13, Vertex 0`). By observing the result graph, I am sure that it gives me the graph with the transposed adjacency matrix. Even if I do `G = networkx.from_numpy_matrix(adj_matrix.T)`, the result does not change. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: it seems it treats it as unordered edge so it treats `(0,13)` and `(13,0)` as the same edge and it get always smaller value `(0,13)`

Comment: Could you edit this question to use text/code fences instead of screencaps? It improves searchability and accessibility of this question.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `networkx.from_numpy_matrix` uses non-directed graphs (have a look at the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_matrix.html)). To represent a directed graph, your call should be:

```py
G = networkx.from_numpy_matrix(adj_matrix, create_using=networkx.DiGraph)
```